# Wordpress apply date after last post of each day in list

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, loops, foreach

could you help me please to apply to last post of each day something like `'<span> this is last post of <date> </span>'`. This is an array with Objects:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 845
                [post_author] => 3
                [post_date] => 2015-02-18 15:01:37
                [post_date_gmt] => 2015-02-18 13:01:37
                [post_status] => publish
                [post_content_filtered] =>
                [post_type] => post
                [post_mime_type] => 
                [comment_count] => 0
                [filter] => raw
...
            )...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange one but what I would do is a bit of trickery where you don't close the current post container until the loop of the next post, then you can compare the current post date with the next one before moving on. try something like this...

```
<?php 

if ( have_posts() )  :

    //Set a variable before the loop so we can test if its the first post
    $first = true;

    //Define 2 variables, one to store current date, one for next date
    $current_day = $next_day = null;

    //Start the loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

        //Set next date
        $next_day = get_the_date( 'd-m-Y' );

        //End the container of the last post on every post except the first
        if( !$first ) {

            //If the current post has a different day to the last include a message
            if( $current_day != $next_day ) {

                echo '<span>This is the last post of ' . get_the_date( 'd-m-Y' ) . '</span>';

            }

            //Close the container of the last post
            echo '<div>';

        }

        //From now on the post is not the first
        $first = false;

        //Now we can set current date
        $current_day = $next_day;

    ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <!-- include the contents of your post here but don't close the container! -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- close the container of the last post -->
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that helps

Regards

Dan

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works great with while looper but unfortunately it dont want to work with my objects :( Im using two files to show posts list. First with:
` function inner($posts, $td_column_number = '') {
        //global $post;
        $buffy = '';
        $td_post_count = 0; // the number of posts rendered
        if (!empty($posts)) {
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                $td_module_10 = new td_module_10($post);
                $buffy .= $td_module_10->render($post);
                $td_post_count++;
            }
        }
        return $buffy;
    }`

Comment: And the second one: class td_module_10 extends td_module {
    function __construct($post) {
        //run the parrent constructor
        parent::__construct($post);
    } function render() {
        ob_start();
        ?>
            <?php echo $this->get_title(td_util::get_option('title'));?>

        <?php return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

Comment: I try to set global variables in first file but it doesnt work... Could you help me please to fix this problem?